# A simple table with a (baseline?) problem

Tags: tables, spacing, baseline, vertical

I am trying to make a simple table with vertical centering, but after I compile there is a larger vertical space between "She" and "He" in the output.
I have taken the table down to its simplest and back again, and the error is still there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c >{\Huge} l  l}

She & {} & {} \\
He & \} & Has \\
It & {} & {} \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you're using the wrong tool for the purpose. Can you provide some more context?

Comment: The output should have the curly bracket vertically centered in the cell so that it indicates She He It in reference to Has.   But right below She is more vertical space than there is between He and It.

Answer (score 1):

with `rcases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{rcases}
    \text{She}\quad \\
    \text{He}       \\
    \text{It}
\end{rcases}\ \text{Has}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]